# Returning index of elements from subarray of a nested list

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested, append

I'm having a lot of issues trying create the following function...horizontal(m) that takes a 2D list (representing a matrix) as input, searches for 4 elements that are in arithmetic progression and returns the locations (indices) of these elements. (An aside: it's also suppose to search for 4 elements in arithmetic progression vertically and diagonally, but I'm just working on the horizontal search now.) I've tried a bunch of different codes, but nothing seems to work out and we haven't worked with nested lists at all in my class at school. Please advise!

```
def horizontal(m):

    diff = m[0][1] - m[0][0]
    index=[]

    for i in range(len(m)-1):
        for j in range(len(m[i])):
            if m[i][j+1] - m[i][j] == diff:
                index.append(m[i][j])
                return index

>>>horizontal([[1, 2, 3, 4],
               [2, 5, 6, 9]])
>>>[1] #but I would like it to return: [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]
```

Also, I'm aware that this currently doesn't limit the function's search to 4 elements...I just wanted to figure out how to properly return the indices before continuing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `index.append([i, j])` instead of your current append line.

This essentially is appending a list which contains the value of `i` as its first element and the value of `j` as its second elemen, which is what you want.

Currently, your code is appending the *value* of the *element* at `m[i][j]`, which isn't what you want.

EDIT (in response to comments):

Fixed the error :-) I had accidentally forgot(ten) to put the brackets around the square brackets.

You need to `return` the `index` list *after* the `for` loops (reindent your `return` line so that it's one indentation level deeper than the declaration of the function (it should be aligned with the `index = []` line)).

Comment: This gives me: TypeError 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I was just about to reply saying I tried it with brackets! :D Sadly, this gives me the output: [[0,0]], so just one of the 4 indices I'd like

Comment: Turns out I had to just fix a line elsewhere in my code! With that and your help, the function returns the various indices now :) thank you!